# How do I make a genrule depend on an external (http_archive)?

Tags: bazel

I'm using bazel to build some C++ and C# sharp code on Windows and Mac. The project I'm working on is split into two parts; a gui part (platform dependent) and a library part. The library is shared with other projects so mixing them into one big project is probably not a good idea.

I have to use a genrule to build the GUI but I can't find a way to make it download the library. genrules do not allow `deps` and I can't find any other suitable way to make bazel do what I need (except mixing the parts, which is what I really don't want to do).

Comment: Is the common library needed during the genrule? If so, just list it in "srcs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules in build files don't depend directly on workspace rules (e.g., `http_archive`), but on the rules which the workspace rules download or generate.

For example, `maven_jar` is a workspace rule which will download a jar, and create a build file with a `java_import` rule for the jar. Then other java rules can depend on the `java_import` as `@name_of_maven_jar_rule//jar`.

The `http_archive` workspace rule similarly downloads the archive, but it doesn't generate a build file. So in order to use anything in that archive, the archive should already contain a build file. Then, other rules in build files can depend on things from that archive as `@name_of_http_archive_rule//package_in_archive:target`.

See
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#http_archive for an example.

Comment: What if the only way I can get a ".jar" is via `http_archive`, and that jar does **not** contain a build file?
how would I make it available similarly to a `maven_jar` "@name_of_maven_jar_rule//jar" ?
I know a build_file can be specified for a `http_archive` but I couldn't get the `java_import` written for it.

Comment: Try using the `http_jar` rule: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_jar